# accessing fusion table with insert into

Tags: google-fusion-tables

i am trying to insert data to a fusion table by the http command :
"https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=INSERT INTO MyTableId (FName, LName, IdNumber, PhoneNumber, PostBox) VALUES ("AAAAAA", "BBBBB", "111111111", "2222222", "99")?key=MyApiKey" . google chrome gives me error code 403 and the same with eclipse WebView, but IE asking for user name and password.
* My google account is not accepted with IE, so what user name and password i have to give?
* What is wrong with Google Chrome and Eclipse?
  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INSERT`'s require the POST-method.  Furthermore an `access_token` must be provided with the request, see: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/articles/oauthfusiontables